# Multiple instances of .click() in dynamic code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex set of dynamic functions that I'm having a problem with more than one instance of .click().  In the below code the first click (saveLocalChart) only calls itself once each time the editChartModal() is called but the removeLocalChart click calls for each time the function was called.

```
function editChartModal(location) {
    if(!localStorage.getItem(location)){
        $('.saveLocalChart').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('add chart: ', location); // DEBUG
            var kpiString = $('#'+location).data('params').kpistring;
            var rtt = $('#'+location).data('params').rtt;
            saveChartLocal(location,kpiString,chartTitle,chartSubTitle,rtt);
            $('.clearChart').show();
            $('.saveChart').hide();
        });
    }else{
        $('.removeLocalChart').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('remove chart: ', location); // DEBUG
            localStorage.removeItem(location);
            $('.clearChart').hide();
            $('.saveChart').show();
        });
    }
}
```

**Console Snapshot:**

[image: Snapshot of console]

Any ideas what could be causing this without having to upload my entire codebase (which has gotten bloated)?

Comment: How many times is `editChartModal()` being called? You're probably setting too many event handlers on `.saveLocalChart` and `.removeLocalChart`.

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you choose to use the `on` function for `removeLocalChart` and not just a plain click function?

Comment: I was combining clicks into a common function and when I pulled the remove chart event in it was using the on() call and I just didn't get around to replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to always unbind the click event before binding a new one.  So just before `.click(...`, add `.unbind('click')` and before `.on('click', ...`, add `.off('click')` and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: the best practice is to not use nested handler

Comment: This worked - I had tried it before but I think I had gotten the implementation wrong - not that the implementation on this entire "let's see how many functions we can nest into one click" is exactly winning any prizes.  I will be redoing this by the end of the week anyway but needed to make it work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `editChartModal()` function, you are binding new click handlers. Just unwrap it from this function.